# Enable fog in GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

I have a rendered view with a cube on it (nice and simple)  I have enabled lighting using a GLKBaseEffect which works well.

I Now want to enable fog and so I thought this would enable it

```
self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

self.effect.fog.enabled = YES;
self.effect.fog.color = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 1.4f, 1.4f, 1.0f);
self.effect.fog.mode =  GLKFogModeExp;
self.effect.fog.density = 1;
```

What am I missing?

2nd question is, should a GLKBaseEffect be per object or per GLView?

Answer (score 0):

This did actually work but I needed to prepareToDraw on each object.  This then caused quite a FPS hit and so I went back to using normal OpenGL 2.0 shaders.

```
self.effect.fog.color = GLKVector4Make(0.3 ,0.3, 0.3, 0.8);
self.effect.fog.enabled = YES;
self.effect.fog.start = 20;
self.effect.fog.end = 30;
self.effect.fog.mode = GLKFogModeLinear;
```